# Создание задержки при отрисовке TextView из ListView

Tags: android, listview, view, textview, adapter

Здравствуйте! 
Есть ListView со своей разметкой:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/bot"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:background="@drawable/strech_chat"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:text="BOT"
    />
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/player"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:background="@drawable/strech_chat"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:text="PLAYER"/>
```

Использую SimpleAdapter
Можно ли создать задержку после появления первого TextView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну например в разметке говорите второму `TextView`, чтобы он был `invisible` или `gone`, в зависимости от того, хотите Вы, чтобы место для второй `TextView` было подготовлено или нет:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/player"
    ...
    android:visibility="invisible"
    />
```

а у `SimpleAdapter` переопределите метод `getView` следующим образом:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    final TextView playerTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.player);
    TextView botTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.bot);
    botTextView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            playerTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }, 1000); // тут настройте время задержки в миллисекундах (1000 мс = 1 секунда)

    return view;
}
```

Чтобы такое происходило только для последнего элемента в списке, не трогайте разметку, достаточно будет обойтись только переопределением того же метода следующим образом:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    if (position == getCount() - 1) {
        final TextView playerTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.player);
        playerTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); // также используйте INVISIBLE или GONE
        TextView botTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.bot);
        botTextView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                playerTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }, 1000); // тут настройте время задержки в миллисекундах (1000 мс = 1 секунда)
    }
    return view;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает! Но есть проблема: пропадают все TextView с одинаковым id. Как применить это только для последнего элемента?

Comment: Обновил ответ и под этот вопрос, в данном случае в разметке атрибут visibility не добавляйте :)

Comment: Огромнейшее спасибо!:)